# c# LinqToSql exception handling when database is offline

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql, exception

Building an C# MVC webapplication with Linq to Sql for querying the SQL database. 
I am trying to catch an exception if the database should go offline to avoid the yellow screen of death.

After debugging, I found two things. First, the creation of the DataContext does not check if the sql server is available. Second, there is an Error message (Or an exception!?) stored in the rows variable.

The Catch statement in the code below is never reached. So I get the Yellow screen of death when trying to read data from the Model in the View.

Why isn't the Catch statement reached?

Code:

```
        try
        {
            //Creating DB Context
            var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["teststring"].ConnectionString;
            TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext(con);

            //Querying database. This should cause an exception to be thrown!?
            var rows =  from s in db.Table
                        orderby s.Id descending
                        select s; 

            //Returning the View with the data
            return View(rows);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorInfo err = new ErrorInfo("Something went wrong when trying to query the database. See the log for details.");
            err.WriteToErrorLog(ex);
            return View("Error", err);
        }
```

Comment: Becuase of deffered execution, the actual call to the db is in the view. you have to materialize it first. Add `.ToList()` and send a list to the view.

Comment: Thx @OfirWinegarten. That should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use SQLException

```
try
    {
        //Creating DB Context
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["teststring"].ConnectionString;
        TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext(con);

        //Querying database. This should cause an exception to be thrown!?
        var rows =  from s in db.Table
                    orderby s.Id descending
                    select s; 

        //Returning the View with the data
        return View(rows);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ErrorInfo err = new ErrorInfo("Something went wrong when trying to query the database. See the log for details.");
        err.WriteToErrorLog(ex);
        return View("Error", err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: as @ofir mentioned you should call `.ToList()` method in order to execute LINQ statement. so you should call it on your try block to be able to catch the exception.

Secondly: 
you shouldn't show Yellow error screen to end users because of security reasons, you can enable CustomError in `web.config` file to show a default page when an exception is thrown and redirect it to an Error page

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/GeneralError">      
</customErrors>
```